# An array of hashes in Ruby - removing unwanted

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes.

Each hash has 3 key-values (plan, number, time)

so it will be like:

```
[0]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 1234, time =>"2016-03-02T13:56:02.000-05:00" }
[1]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 1234, time =>"2016-03-02T14:56:02.000-05:00" }
[2]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 1234, time =>"2016-03-02T13:59:02.000-05:00" }
[3]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 1234, time =>"2016-03-02T12:56:02.000-05:00" }
[4]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 4444, time =>"2016-03-02T16:42:02.000-05:00" }
[5]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 4444, time =>"2016-03-02T16:45:02.000-05:00" }
[6]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 4444, time =>"2016-03-02T16:44:02.000-05:00" }
[7]{plan => "my_plan", number=> 4444, time =>"2016-03-02T16:50:02.000-05:00" }
```

etc etc

I want to keep the ones with the latest time (greatest time).

So where the number is "1234", I want to keep this row:

```
{plan => "my_plan", number=> 1234, time =>"2016-03-02T14:56:02.000-05:00" }
```

and discard the rest.

And for number "4444" I would keep:

```
{plan => "my_plan", number=> 4444, time =>"2016-03-02T16:50:02.000-05:00" }
```

as it is the one with the greatest date for that number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input = [
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 1234, time: "2016-03-02T13:56:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 1234, time: "2016-03-02T14:56:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 1234, time: "2016-03-02T13:59:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 1234, time: "2016-03-02T12:56:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 4444, time: "2016-03-02T16:42:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 4444, time: "2016-03-02T16:45:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 4444, time: "2016-03-02T16:44:02.000-05:00" },
  {plan: "my_plan", number: 4444, time: "2016-03-02T16:50:02.000-05:00" }
]

input.group_by { |e| e[:number] }
     .values
     .map { |vals| vals.sort_by { |e| e[:time] }.last }

#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#    :number => 1234,
#      :plan => "my_plan",
#      :time => "2016-03-02T14:56:02.000-05:00"
#  },
#  [1] {
#    :number => 4444,
#      :plan => "my_plan",
#      :time => "2016-03-02T16:50:02.000-05:00"
#  }
# ]
```

Whether you are free to use brilliant [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash) implementation, it’s even more expressive:

```
require 'hashie'
input.map { |h| Hashie::Mash.new(h) }
     .group_by(&:number)
     .values
     .map { |vals| vals.sort_by(&:time).last }
```

**NB** whether datetime values might be in different timezones, it’s safer to explicitly convert strings to `Time` instances before sorting:

```
input.group_by { |e| e[:number] }
     .values
     .map { |vals| vals.sort_by { |e| Time.parse e[:time] }.last }
```